# Sum two rows (one previous row and one is current row in same table) in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
Date_on      deposited  withdrawal   in_bank
2012-09-1      3000       2000        50000
2012-09-2/t    4000/t        0        54000
2013-09-3/t    3000       2000        55000
```

Now I want to execute a query to add the deposited amounts and subtract the withdrawals from the previous days entry `in_bank`. How can I do that? Can any one help me on that? This is my query:

```
select date_on, in_bank,((in_bank+deposited)-withdrawal)
  from  tablename where date_on > '2012-09-01' order by date_on
```

Comment: What is the desired output for the sample data you posted?

Comment: i want date_on and in_bank( current date) and in_bank(previousday)-withdraw+deposited

Comment: Your database Oracle or mysql? You've tagged your question with `mysql` tag and `plsql`. So what the RDBMS you are using?

Comment: database is mysql.. sorry for plsql

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT today.withdrawal, today.deposited, today.date_on,
  (IFNULL(today.deposited, 0) - IFNULL(today.withdrawal, 0)) + IFNULL((SELECT in_bank FROM tablename AS yesterday WHERE yesterday.date_on = DATE_SUB(today.date_on, INTERVAL 1 DAY)), 0)
FROM tablename AS today
WHERE date_on BETWEEN '2012-09-01' AND '2012-09-02'
ORDER BY date_on ASC
```

The query will assume the balance was zero if no previous days date can be found.

Added a fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8261/14

Comment: it will sum the deposited and withdrawal then minus it but waht i need i have given in bold

Comment: but i want to add previous day bank_in amount

Comment: Fixed - I'll create a fiddle also

Comment: Added the fiddle and fixed query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  t1.date_on,
  t1.in_bank,
  (
    SELECT in_bank
    FROM
    (
      SELECT *, (@rownum2 := @rownum2 +1) rank
      FROM Table1,(SELECT @rownum2 :=0 ) t
      ORDER BY date_on 
     ) t2 WHERE t1.rank - t2.rank = 1
   ) - t1.withdrawal - deposited "total"
FROM
(
  SELECT *, (@rownum := @rownum +1) rank
  FROM Table1,(SELECT @rownum :=0 ) t
  ORDER BY date_on 
) t1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f09a5/5)

Comment: total should come same as bank_in dear

Comment: @Ashishsingh - `Total` is computed the same way you asked. And how the `total` should be the same as `bank_in` so what the point of calculating it? My query gives total values: `NULL`(becuase it is the first one with no previous), `46000`, `49000` What is the total values that you want to output the sample data?>

Comment: but if run the query from the second line then also it is giving me null

Comment: @Ashishsingh - What do you mean from the second line?

Comment: if i start to run the query from the second line  of the table then ...by giving where condition..

Comment: @Ashishsingh - Can you please modify the [**demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f09a5/5) explaining that issue? sorry I couldn't understand what do you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  date_on, 
  in_bank, 
  (( ISNULL(in_bank, 0) + ISNULL(in_deposited,0)) - ISNULL(withdrawal,0))
FROM tablename 
WHERE date_on > '2012-09-01' 
ORDER BY date_on
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with mysql but this might help

```
select account.*,D.expectable from account left join 
(
select deposited - withdrawal + in_bank as expectable,DATE_ADD(Date_on,INTERVAL 1 DAY) as nDate from account
)
D on account.Date_on = D.nDate
```